# mix-blend-mode with multiple background sections and absolute positioned text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get `mix-blend-mode: difference` to work on a `position-absolute` paragraph on top of a row of multiple background columns.

Upon hovering over the individual columns, the overlay div would fade and and I was hoping to see the text color changes as the color becomes vibrant, but right now it is just a yellowish color.

Because of how the overlay and backgrounds are positioned, the only way I found to make this text go on top is the use of `z-index`, and I have found that it messes with the stacking context, causing the text to not blend as expected.

How do I get the paragraph color to blend as expected while keeping the layout?

```html
<div class="container-fluid px-0 art">
    <div class="display-4 title center-piece">Art Projects</div>
    <div class="container center-piece blend">
      <h5 class="fw-bold">Bacon ipsum dolor amet sausage salami meatloaf, exercitation ad ham hock aliqua ham tail ut. Mollit t-bone ut bacon cupim sirloin officia capicola tail qui swine shank turkey. In adipisicing boudin spare ribs est officia eu elit. Enim nulla swine ham hock dolore.</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-100 g-0 max-vh-100">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 h-100 position-relative">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background: url(https://t3.gstatic.com/licensed-image?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8pZt_b2Bh9Kybwvkg8jl8QEyuOuRGAH97yNPwj4tYRJZKrD-1kug6v5EQHIv5sjWM)"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 h-100 position-relative">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background: url(https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/900x510/https://www.forbes.com/home-improvement/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/download-23.jpg)"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 h-100 position-relative">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="image" style="background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg/640px-Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.art {
    position: relative;
    
    .title {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: maroon;
    }
  
    .center-piece {
        pointer-events: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        width: fit-content;
        height: fit-content;
        z-index: 1;
        
        &.blend {
            mix-blend-mode: difference;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        h5 {
            margin-top: 6em;
            color: slate;
            width: fit-content;
        }
    }

    .parent {
        height: 80vh;
    }

    .overlay {
        background-color: beige;
        opacity: 0.8;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%; height: 100%;
        transition: all ease 0.3s;

        &:hover {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }

    .image {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dazhs8pv/2/